# How to apply eval one list of string

Tags: python

My input is `s = ("{'A':{},'B':''}", 'Test', '2020-09-09 15:19:28','emp', 'emp@jod.com')`

My expected out is  `({'A':{},'B':''}, 'Test', '2020-09-09 15:19:28','emp', 'emp@jod.com')`

I have tried eval `s[0] + s[1:]` but could not help

Comment: Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eval(s[0]) + s[1:]
```

or `import ast` as in the comment